# Jquery how do I append to div, that doesn't exist at the beginging of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

At a certain point a new div is created that did not exist on the page beforehand

```
document.getElementById("LightBoxNumber").innerHTML = "<div class=\"WinnerBanner\">Congrats to all Winners!</div>";
```

from

```
<div id="LightBoxNumber" class="LightBoxShadow" style="font-size: xxx-large;"></div>
```

To

```
<div id="LightBoxNumber" class="LightBoxShadow" style="font-size: xxx-large;"><div class="WinnerBanner">Congrats!</div></div>
```

I would like to run a separate  to append into that div at the moment it is created
i.e. create `<span></span>`

```
<div id="LightBoxNumber" class="LightBoxShadow" style="font-size: xxx-large;"><div class="WinnerBanner">Congrats!</div><span></span></div>
```

I have tested a few options and ways but cannot figure this out

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.WinnerBanner').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('.WinnerBanner').length > 0){
            $(this).prepend('Yes!');
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    if( $('div.WinnerBanner').length > 0 ){
        $('#SelectNumbersBox').append('HHHHHHHHHHHH');
    }
    $('#SelectNumbersBox').append('DDDDDDDDDD');
});

$('body').change(function(event){
    if( $('div.WinnerBanner').length > 0 ){
        $('#SelectNumbersBox').append('HHHHHHHHHHHH');
    }
    $('#SelectNumbersBox').append('DDDDDDDDDD');
});
```

Comment: While there are ways to detect a change to the DOM, I would suggest that you look into ways for your code to be notified when the change is made.  If it's your code that's making the change (that you want to detect) then [raise an event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) and listen for it.   If it's an API, then it's possible that API has a *hook* (either an event or a callback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch the parent div for changes and then run your code when it changes

```js
const div = document.getElementById("LightBoxNumber");

const config = {
  attributes: false,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.type === "childList") {
      mutation.target.querySelector('.WinnerBanner').prepend('Yes! ');

      // if you use your jquery you can do $(mutation.target).find('.WinnerBanner').prepend('Yes! ');

      //optional disconnect the observer after the change:
      observer.disconnect();
    }
  }

};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(div, config);


div.innerHTML = "<div class=\"WinnerBanner\">Congrats to all Winners!</div>";
```

```html
<div id="LightBoxNumber" class="LightBoxShadow" style="font-size: xxx-large;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect when the dynamic content is injected in to the DOM and make your own updates based on that event.

Here's a basic working example of how to do that:

```js
// Somewhere in another library, far, far away.
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("LightBoxNumber").innerHTML = "<div class=\"WinnerBanner\">Congrats to all Winners!</div>", 1000);

// in your codebase
const lightbox = document.querySelector('#LightBoxNumber');

const mutationConfig = { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: false };
const mutationHandler = mutations => {
  for (const mutation of mutations) {
    if (lightbox.querySelector('.WinnerBanner')) {
      observer.disconnect(); // important to remove the observer, otherwise you'll end up in an infinite loop!
      
      // create your new element here...
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.textContent = 'This is your new dynamic content!';
      lightbox.append(span);
    }
  }
};
const observer = new MutationObserver(mutationHandler);
observer.observe(lightbox, mutationConfig);
```

```html
<div id="LightBoxNumber" class="LightBoxShadow" style="font-size: xxx-large;"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think the `for (const mutation of mutations) {..}` loop is required.

Comment: Potentially not for a simple example, but I left it in intentionally in case the actual use case the OP has is more complex than just a single div being updated once.

Comment: Thank you, I would have marked it as the answer, as this is really good for someone else who might be looking for something more. Really appreciate it.